# Scale an image to fit the screen without changing its aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox, scale

How can I have an image take scale the screen while keeping it's aspect ratio in CSS? For example, if I have an image that is taller than it is wide its `height` should be `100%` (and `width: auto;`). But if the image is wider than it is tall its `width` should be `100%` (and `height: auto;`).

Can I do this in CSS?

If the `height` and the `width` are both `100%` than the image is all squished together like so:

[image]

If the `height` and `width` are both `auto`, the image scales correctly unless it is smaller than the screen's size, then it leaves gaps around its edges:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `object-fit: cover`, this ensures that the image doesn't lose its aspect ratio. You can also use a percentage value like `width: 70%`, and `height: auto` so the image scales down when resized